# How to search a cassandra collection map using QueryBuilder

Tags: cassandra, query-builder, cql3, datastax-java-driver

In my cassandra table i have a collection of Map also i have indexed the map keys.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.collection_test(
  name text,
  year text,
  attributeMap map<text,text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((name, year))
);




CREATE INDEX ON collection_test (attributeMap);
```

The QueryBuilder syntax is as below:

```
select().all().from("test", "collection_test")
                .where(eq("name", name)).and(eq("year", year));
```

How should i put where condition on `attributeMap`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you will need to create an index on the keys in your map.  By default, an index created on a map indexes the values of the map, not the keys.  There is special syntax to index the keys:

```
CREATE INDEX attributeKeyIndex ON collection_test (KEYS(attributeMap));
```

Next, to `SELECT` from a map with indexed keys, you'll need the `CONTAINS KEY` keyword.  But currently, there is not a definition for this functionality in the query builder API.  However, there is an open ticket to support it: [JAVA-677](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-677)

Currently, to accomplish this with the Java Driver, you'll need to build your own query or use a prepared statement:

```
    PreparedStatement statement = _session.prepare("SELECT * " +
            "FROM test.collection_test " +
            "WHERE attributeMap CONTAINS KEY ?");
    BoundStatement boundStatement = statement.bind(yourKeyValue);
    ResultSet results = _session.execute(boundStatement);
```

Finally, you should read through the DataStax doc on [When To Use An Index](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/ddl/ddl_when_use_index_c.html).  Secondary indexes are known to not perform well.  I can't imagine that a secondary index on a collection would be any different.